# youtube video not resizing properly

Tags: html, css, youtube

Hi I have a background youtube video. I need it to be responsive. As I decrease the screen width it gets thinner, so that's good, but the height isn't altering correctly - it looks a bit like its shrinking down too fast.... You can see it here http://www.onscreencounselling.com/

What's wrong please

```
<?php if(is_page('homepage')){ ?>
<div id="video_background_video_0" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
            <iframe id="video_background_video_0_yt" style="position: absolute; top: -179px; left: 0px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="1349" height="759" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1CXFhQ33_xs?loop=0&amp;start=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onscreencounselling.com"></iframe></div>

        <?php } ?>
```

And this css

```
#video_background_video_0 {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hey @maxelcat try just making height:100% instead of height:0; in #video_background_video_0. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this directly to the editor? This is a css fix.

```
 .page iframe {
  width: 560px !important;
  height: 315px !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline styling from your `iframe` and it'll work: https://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/65sL59v8/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline `top` value from `iframe`
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lz3umzu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove Inline style from both and add

```
overflow-hidden;
```

to div and it will work.